# Storing a column value in another column every time code is ran

Tags: python, pandas

*PYTHON CODING*

My goal is to store a column value in another specific column each time that the Python code is ran. It will basically be comparing two excel spreadsheets (yesterday and today) for a specific column. For example, # of candidates interviewed is the column value I want to pull from and store it in a new column '# of Candidates Interviewed Yesterday'

*File #1*

**School | # of Candidates Interviewed Today**

ABC    | 25 Interviewed

*File #2*

**School | # of Candidates Interviewed Today  | # of Candidates Interviewed Yesterday**

ABC    | 30 Interviewed                     | 25 Interviewed

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I understood what you want to do, but I'm assuming you want to change the values from certain columns from your dataframe, while keeping the old values on another column. If that is the case, here's how you could do that, although I do not recommend using it for anything other than testing purposes:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    """
    PROBABLY NOT A GOOD IDEA!

    Pandas DataFrame class with custom `__setattr__`, and `__setitem__` that store
    the previous values from a given column, before modifying it.
    """

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if hasattr(self, key):
            self[key + '_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S')] = self[key]
        self[key] = value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if hasattr(self, key):
            super().__setitem__(key + '_' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S'), self[key])
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

## Example on how it works:

dictionary = {'name1': 'A', 'name2': 'B', 'value1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'value2': [6, 3, 4, 5]}

df = CustomDataFrame(dictionary)
print(df)
"""
  name1 name2  value1  value2
0     A     B       1       6
1     A     B       2       3
2     A     B       3       4
3     A     B       4       5
"""

# Modifying values from column "name1":

df['name1'] = 'B'
print(df)
"""
  name1 name2  value1  value2 name1_2022_08_15_205120
0     B     B       1       6                       A
1     B     B       2       3                       A
2     B     B       3       4                       A
3     B     B       4       5                       A
"""

# Modifying "name1" once again:

df.name1 = 'C'
print(df)
"""
  name1 name2  value1  value2 name1_2022_08_15_205120 name1_2022_08_15_205313
0     C     B       1       6                       A                       B
1     C     B       2       3                       A                       B
2     C     B       3       4                       A                       B
3     C     B       4       5                       A                       B
"""
```